# Why do I get a run error from Aptana on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: java, ubuntu, aptana

I've installed Aptana Studio 3 and Java 11 on Ubuntu 20.04. When I run it I get as far as the workplace dialog and it then crashes. The error log has numerous references to eclipse, such as:

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2020-05-14 20:08:37.125 !MESSAGE
>   Application error !STACK 1 org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct    at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:410)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:318)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultHeadlessContext(E4Application.java:491)

and many similar lines.

What am I doing wrong?

John

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer. Aptana won't work with Java 11. I replaced that with Java 8 and all is well.